# How to send Time Triggered Notification using parse.com in Android?

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications

I have implemented push notification using parse. But I want to send notification to user at specific time in their specific time-zones. I know that we can send notification to all devices at once from the dashboard. But can we trigger the notification from within the app?

Right now I just check the system date and display the data matching from my Parse class.

But I want to send a notification to the user at specific time!

Code to get system date!

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    final String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Code that checks date and displays relevant info!

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> _temparrayList = HelperFile
            .loadArrayListFromFile(MainActivity.this, HelperFile.DAILYVERSE);

    if (_temparrayList != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < _temparrayList.size(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = _temparrayList.get(i);

            if (formattedDate.equals(map.get("date"))) {
                verse = map.get("verse");
                book = map.get("book");
                book_text.setText(book);
                verse_text.setText(verse);
            } else if (new_formattedDate.equals(map.get("date"))) {
                verse = map.get("verse");
                book = map.get("book");
                book_text.setText(book);
                verse_text.setText(verse);
            }

            else {
                value = true;
                new RemoteDataTask().execute();

            }

        }
    } else {
        verse_text.setText("Data Yet To Update, Please Refresh");
        refresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    }
```

The Async task that makes the query from Parse!

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (value == false) {
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Daily Verse Is Updating");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "DailyVerse");
        query.orderByDescending("date");
        try {
            ob = query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Retrieve object "name" from Parse.com database
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        for (ParseObject country : ob) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            String book = (String) country.get("book");
            String verse = (String) country.get("verse");
            String date = (String) country.get("date").toString();

            map.put("book", book);
            map.put("verse", verse);
            map.put("date", date);

            arrayList.add(map);
        }
        HelperFile.writeArrayListToFile(arrayList, MainActivity.this,
                HelperFile.DAILYVERSE);
        if (value == false) {
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }
}
```

So the QUESTION is How will I send a notification to the user everyday at 8:00 AM?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to build a kind of "worker" or "job" within your android application. I think it's not the best option. But to do a "kind" of this, you should implement +service and call [startService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29) method. I've already used Parse and I normally send user notifications by push firing by my webservice, and my worker/job is in my webservice(back-end application).

Hope it could be useful for you! =)

Comment: Isn't there any way by which we can send notification from within the app? I  don't want to run a webservice just for a notification!
Thanks @Franze for the reply.

Comment: The point is: When your notification will be created?? Ok, you know the date and time, but WHO will do it for you? 1)Your Android Application needs to be running 2)A service - that is running in background. You need to choose one of them and create your notification.

Comment: My application is already running in background. I can determine the System time as well. But I don't know how to make a notification from the app itself.

The logic what I thought was to get System time, and then trigger notification to the device! But I don't know it's implementation.

Comment: Did you try to follow this stuff: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html ?

Comment: If you are still interested in sending notifications through Parse Push but doing so through the application take a look at this: https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#sending-channels/Android